# AngularJS: Using $compile to append html to a web page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a dynamic web page that is generated by previous entries that the user has made. This means going through a list of possible inputs they could have selected then appending them to the html within a directive.

So that my ng- tags all work I need to run this big chunk of html through $compile so that they still work. This has been working fine, my issue now is that I am trying to do more complex fields that use custom directives or jquery classes that just refuse to run properly after being put through $compile.

For example -

```
<div data-j-signature="obj.Test" data-pen-color="#0000ff" data-line-color="#00000" style="border:1px #000 solid;"></div><div class="col-sm-11">
```

This uses a well used angular library called JSignature, and will work fine when put somewhere in my web page, but not when going through the compile process.

I'm not necessarily looking for an answer for that specific problem as I feel this will be a constant problem with more fields that I try to add. Does anyone have any general advice on how to go about getting around this? Is there an alternative I'm not seeing?

Here is my html -

```
<div ng-repeat="Question in Questions">
    <question-type></question-type>
</div>
```

Here is the important part of what my directive does at the end after combining a lot of strings of html together -

```
var compiledHtml = $compile(stringOfHtml)(scope);
element.append(compiledHtml);
```

Comment: Who creates the datepicker instance? A directive or an init script?

Comment: Hi, I took the datepicker out of my post because I thought it was more relevant showing an angular example that wasn't working.

Comment: `JSignature` is jQuery too. If you wrap a directive around it, that probably expects the element being already present in the DOM, but you insert it after compilation.

Comment: Ah yeah... I was just thinking of the directive and not the library. After checking this a bit more, it does hit the jsignature directive first, then compiles in my directive, then goes into the jquery jsignature library. Do you think delaying the compile to be at the very end might solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> This uses a jquery datepicker and will work fine normally, but not when being appended then compiled in my directive.

And this is really the core of your issue. You cannot expect jQuery plugins to work properly inside of Angular application, simply because their lifecycles are not very good coincides. I will explain better.

When you run application, some HTML with directives and binding Angular gets parsed and compiled by Angular. this i fine. At this point your jQuery plugins will probably even initialize properly, because they usually just need to have DOM rendered. However what's going to happen when you append newly compiled dynamic HTML? Angular will pick it up well because you call `$compile`. But jQuery might get desynchronized and never reinitialize plugins.

That's the main reason why you should not use jQuery the way we are all used to. Ideally jQuery usage (and DOM manipulation in general) should be limited to custom directives only. This is the only way to be 100% sure that both Angular and jQuery update/initialize their stuff at the right moment.

So.. You need a datepicker? Great! There are many Angular directives available (for example, [Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) datepicker)that simply wraps jQuery plugins into linking function, thus making it compatible with Angular workflow and digest cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I do plan on getting rid of the jquery, so maybe I should have just used an angular example that is not working, I'll update my post.

Comment: Edited my post if you have any more suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $compile){
$scope.updateData = function(){
    $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: 'abc.com',
      data: angular.element('#form').serialize(),
      headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).
    then(function(result){
        var temp = $compile(result.data)($scope);
        angular.element('#showhtml').html(temp);
    }).catch(function(response){
    }).finally(function() {
    });
}
});
```